# Determine category in taxonomy of current custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Using a php statement - how can I determine the name of the category in a taxonomy of the current custom post type that a user is browsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) is the most obvious answer. Per the Codex:

> Returns an array of objects, one object for each category assigned to
>   the post. This tag may be used outside The Loop by passing a post id
>   as the parameter.

Or [`wp_get_post_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories) as in this example from the Codex:

```
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
$cats = array();

foreach($post_categories as $c){
    $cat = get_category( $c );
    $cats[] = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );
}
```

But your question is *very* light on detail. It is hard to tell exactly what you need.

Comment: it's hard to explain this at the moment.. thanks for pointing out  wp_get_post_categories  - this should be what i need